# Android with AspectJ - DropDown of Spinner wont show

Tags: android, aspectj, android-spinner

i'm using aspectJ in my Android project because of monkeytalk ( cross platform testing framework ). But since i converted my project to an aspectJ project, the dropdown of the spinner is gone/invisible...

If i convert the project back to a non aspectJ project everything works as it should ( except for the monkeytalk agent... ).

I also created my own spinner and overrode onTouch, to check if the event arrives. The touch is recognized, but the dropdown view won't open!

Has anyone else similar problems or some help?

edit: i've tested this on an galaxy nexus running 4.0.4 and sony xperia running 2.1

Thanks in advance

Flo

My TestCode from onCreate ( as you see it's as simple as it can be ):

```
    Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById( R.id.spinner1 );

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monkeytalk team declared this as a bug in their agent. They hope to release a fixed version this week.

Thanks anyway :)